# What is meant by rolling 2-year averages in College Scorecard?

Tags: collegescorecard

What is meant by rolling 2-year averages in College Scorecard?Is this simply including two cohorts in a single calculation?

Answer (score 3):

For many elements, data are pooled across two years of data to reduce year-over-year variability in figures (i.e. repayment rate, debt figures). These data elements represent the weighted average of two consecutive years of data. The cohorts are overlapping  or “rolling”. For instance, the 2010 and 2011 cohorts are combined to create a repayment rate; and then for the next year, the 2011 and 2012 cohorts are combined.